# Can't get relative location of local files - "path to me as text " not working in Xcode

Tags: applescript-objc

I have having real trouble getting the path of objects within my Xcode project - previously in another thread adayzdone suggested to use:

```
set parentDirectory to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
```

Which works brilliantly... in Applescript Script Editor, but causes this error when included in my Applescriptobjc project in Xcode :

Can’t make «class ocid» id «data optr00000000609B220080600000» into type constant. (error -1700)

Still has me stumped!

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

```
set ImagePath to current application's NSBundle's mainBundle()'s bundlePath() as text & "/Contents/Resources/imageName.png"
```

Thanks.